# Git branches - statuses mixed-up?

Tags: git, branch, status

I have a local master for my repository cloned and I update the same on daily basis with pull request

I have created 2 branches with following commands and I work on both. These are also frequently rebased to master

```
    git checkout -b bug1

    git checkout -b feature1
```

I switched to branch b1, pushed some changes for bug1 and waiting for review completion. Meanwhile, I switch to feature1 branch and start making changes but yet to either 'git add' or 'git commit' on feature1 branch.

Observations

- In this state, when I switch to either master or bug1 branches and do `git status`, I see the changes I am doing on branch 'feature1'.
- `git log` on master and feature branches reflect correct-state
- `git log` on bug1 branch also reflects correct-state with my last commit waiting for gerrit review

Additional Info (if it's of any significance)

- I use windows git client and use 'git review' for pushing code from branches

Clarifications

- Is is normal that I see the changes being done in one branch on another one when I check with `git status`?
- In such as state, if I do `git add -a` in branch bug1 would it not result in changes of feature1 branch ALSO go as part of next commit and push on bug1 branch ?
- Am I doing something terribly wrong?

Comment: Your working directory and staging area aren't associated with any branch.  Only commits are organised in a graph with branches etc.  Local changes will simply be kept when switching branches, provided that the files you changed don't differ between the two branches.

Answer (score 0):

> Is is normal that I see the changes being done in one branch on another one when I check with git status?

Yes, this is normal behaviour for git. Since you have not applied your changes to any branch (your changes unstated) it's auto merged if it's possible.

> In such as state, if I do `git add -a` in branch bug1 would it not result in changes of feature1 branch ALSO go as part of next commit and push on bug1 branch ?

No, it would not.

> Am I doing something terribly wrong?

It looks like not this time. But your level of understanding how does git works seems pretty bad. I recommend you to read [this book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) and to use search at [this website](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: That was perfect. I tried out and it worked. Yes. I will read those links for sure. Thanks Maxim